# wrong constructor used in template class

Tags: c++, templates

I need to use inside my templated class a `boost::interprocess::mutex`
Inside my function I declared my variable the way below

```
  named_mutex mutex(open_only, m_name.c_str() 
  ,permissions(0666));
```

I don't know why I cannot compile and I get an error below.
How is it possible that the compiler doesn't use the right constructor (it tries to match a constructor having const reference) and how to force using the right one?

```
    error: no matching function for call to   
    boost::interprocess::named_mutex::named_mutex(const 
    boost::interprocess::open_only_t&,   const char*, boost::interprocess::permissions)’
    /usr/local/include/boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp:140: note: 
    candidates are: 
    boost::interprocess::named_mutex::named_mutex(boost::interprocess::open_only_t, const char*)
```

Comment: you are right. I fixed it!

Comment: Please stop using `<code></code>` tags. You should be marking up inline code with `\`backticks\``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor that takes an `open_only_t` doesn't take a permission parameter. Wouldn't really make sense - you're trying to open an existing mutex, not to create one.

Remove the permissions and it should find the proper overload.

Comment: Thanks Mat! I didn't spot it.